# The letter E is thrown away from the word GEBON . How many ways can rest of the letters be jumbled so that O does not appear at the beginning?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The letter E is thrown away from the word GEBON. How many ways can rest of the letters be jumbled so that O does not appear at the beginning?
This a combinatorics problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** The solution is based on the assumption that a letter can appear only once in the word.

After removing E from the word GEBON, the word left is GBON.

Now the letter at the start can be G, B or N i.e, you've **three** options to start the letter.

After selecting the start letter, you're left with **three** other letters for the second letter in the word (for example, if the first letter of the word is G, then the second letter can be B, O or N).

After picking the first two letters, you can select the third letter in **two** different ways and the then you have a **single** choice left for the last letter.

Hence the total number of combinations will be $3 \times 3 \times 2 \times 1 = 18$.

==============================================================================

If the letters in the word can be repeated, then the total number of combinations can be $3 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 192$.